# Send email in iterations. c#

Tags: c#, email

My application restarts when one iteration is over.
I need to send email when there's an exception in the code/application.

Let's say an exception has come in the application, I am sending an email.
1st iteration.. exception is sent in an email.
the application restarts the process.
2nd iteration.. when exception comes it has to check last sent email time.. if it is less than 30mins,don't send an email.  If it is more than 30mins send email.

How can I code it such way?

I tried timers. that didn't work.

Here are few lines from the code.

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log("An exception has occured in the application: " + ex.Message);
            exceptionMessage = ex.Message;
            failureEmail = true;
            SendFailureMail(exceptionMessage);
        }


    private void SendFailureMail(String message)
    {

        emailTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm");
        //if (emailTime.Equals("00:00") || emailTime.Equals("1:00") || emailTime.Equals("2:00") || emailTime.Equals("3:00") 
        //    || emailTime.Equals("4:00") || emailTime.Equals("5:00") || emailTime.Equals("6:00") || emailTime.Equals("7:00") 
        //    || emailTime.Equals("8:00") || emailTime.Equals("9:00") || emailTime.Equals("10:00") || emailTime.Equals("11:00") 
        //    || emailTime.Equals("12:00"))
        //{
        if (failureEmail)
        {
            eMailID = string.Empty;
            subject = string.Empty;
            mailBody = string.Empty;
            eMailID = eMailIDFailure;
            subject = eMailSubjectFailure;
            emailBodyGeneric.Append(message);
            mailBody = emailBodyGeneric.ToString();

            if (sendmail())
            {
                Log("Mail Sent");

            }
            else
            {
                Log("Sending Mail Failed.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Write the last sent datetime to a file; if the file exists and its date time is less than 30 mins ago do nothing, otherwise send the email and save the datetime back to disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the to a log file with an timestamp when the email was sent.

This can easily be accomplished.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
        private static void LogEmailSent(DateTime date)
        {
            using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("my path"))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(date);

            }
        }
        private static bool EmailSent()
        {
            bool logged = false;

            //It is a good idea to include try catch and a good idea to check if the file exists;
            if (!File.Exists("my file"))
                return false;

            using(StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader("my path"))
            {

                while(!rdr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = rdr.ReadLine();
                    DateTime dateLogged = Convert.ToDateTime(line);
                    TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dateLogged);
                    if(difference.TotalMinutes <= 30)
                    {
                        logged = true;
                    }


                    break; //the file contains a line, so try to parse the datetime;

                }
            }
            return logged;

        }
    }
}
```

Remeber that is a an example. A lot of tweeking can be done.